# How do I get natural dimensions of an image using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, dimensions

I have this code so far:

```
var img = document.getElementById('draggable');
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

However this gets me the html attributes - css styles. I want to get dimensions of the actual image resource, of the file.

I need this because upon uploading an image, it's width gets set to 0px and I have no idea why or where this is happening. To prevent it I want to get the actual dimension and reset them. Is this possible?

Edit: Even when I try to get naturalWidth I get 0 as a result. I've added a picture. The weird thing is that it only happens when I upload new files and upon refresh it's working as it should.

http://oi39.tinypic.com/3582xq9.jpg

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You could use `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight`, these properties contain the actual, non-modified width and height of the image, but you have to wait until the image has loaded to get them

```
var img = document.getElementById('draggable');

img.onload = function() {
    var width  = img.naturalWidth;
    var height = img.naturalHeight;
}
```

This is only supported from IE9 and up, if you have to support older browser you could create a new image, set it's source to the same image, and if you don't modify the size of the image, it will return the images natural size, as that would be the default when no other size is given

```
var img     = document.getElementById('draggable'),
    new_img = new Image();

new_img.onload = function() {
    var width  = this.width,
        heigth = this.height;
}

new_img.src = img.src;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HBWyk/1/)

Comment: This solves it, thank you. Is wrapping my code inside jQuery.ready() function not enough since the image is not loaded by then? I have this trouble only when uploading a new file to the server.

Comment: Images are not loaded when the jQuery DOM ready function fires, only the DOM is ready. `$(window).on('load')` will fire when everything has loaded, but just attaching the onload event handler directly to the image would be better IMO.

Comment: this is very helpful

Answer (score 18):

There are `img.naturalHeight` and `img.naturalWidth` which give you the width and height of the image itself, and not the DOM element.

Comment: Does'nt work in IE8 or below, and not in Opera as far as I know.

Comment: Interesting. Do note that for IE, this is for IE9 or above. I looked it up and stumbled upon this snippet that adds `.naturalHeight()` and `.naturalWidth()` to jQuery. Just thought I could share this info bit here: http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/naturalwidth-and-naturalheight-in-ie/

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following function I made.

Function

```
function getImageDimentions(imageNode) {
  var source = imageNode.src;
  var imgClone = document.createElement("img");
  imgClone.src = source;
  return {width: imgClone.width, height: imgClone.height}
}
```

html:

```
<img id="myimage" src="foo.png">
```

use it like this

```
var image = document.getElementById("myimage"); // get the image element
var dimentions = getImageDimentions(image); // get the dimentions
alert("width: " + dimentions.width + ", height: " + dimentions.height); // give the user a visible alert of the dimentions
```

Comment: this looks like a solution for < IE8 as described in the top answer, so +1 although I don't like that this extra processing has to affect sane browser users. however, perhaps you could feature detect if naturalWidth exists, and if not then run this code.