# How do I prevent Mozilla from up-scaling images on HiDPI displays?

Tags: html, css, firefox, seamonkey

When viewing a raster image, all more or less recent *Mozilla* products (e. g.: *Firefox* and *SeaMonkey*) transform it into a full HTML document, e. g.:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height;">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resource://gre/res/ImageDocument.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resource://gre/res/TopLevelImageDocument.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome://global/skin/media/TopLevelImageDocument.css">
    <title>googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png (PNG Image, 544&nbsp;×&nbsp;184 pixels)</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
  </body>
</html>
```

The content of the default CSS styles can be viewed here:

- [`resource://gre/res/ImageDocument.css`](https://gist.github.com/unix-junkie/dfc18b32847a1ba4fff5f2d3001e6835)
- [`resource://gre/res/TopLevelImageDocument.css`](https://gist.github.com/unix-junkie/383a4804f15dca53af3cd2a059b9c4ca)
- [`chrome://global/skin/media/TopLevelImageDocument.css`](https://gist.github.com/unix-junkie/8a1cc012765507081434b0a2ca0816d9)

The problem is, on HiDPI displays, low-resolution images often get up-scaled (for instance, on a 4k display they're enlarged by a factor of **x1.5**).

Which extra styles do I need to apply to the generated HTML in order for images to be always displayed in their original size (i. e. **1:1**)?

I'm looking for the proper way to customize either `userContent.css` or `userChrome.css`.

More on `userChrome.css`:

- https://www.userchrome.org/what-is-userchrome-css.html
- https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/7dvtw0/guide_how_to_edit_your_context_menu/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/FirefoxCSS/

Comment: Why dont you use inline styling `style="width: 200px;height: 50px;`

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa Because I want the CSS to be generic, suitable to viewing **any** image.

Comment: Is this an issue only in Firefox? If not, it should be relatively easy to fix with CSS.

Comment: @jhpratt my question is exactly about how this can be fixed with pure CSS, but in a size independent way (i. e. the one which allows to fix it once and for all).

Comment: Looking into this a bit more, it's definitely possible to do in CSS _to an extent_, but it would require an exhaustive list of DPIs / pixel ratios. A tiny bit of JS could solve this if you're willing to accept such a solution.

Comment: check `style="width: 100%; height: auto;"`

Comment: I don't have 4k display, so I tried to reproduce it with latest Firefox and device emulation. No success. Also I don't see anything in browser CSS which could affect image width/height. Could you please check that you zoom level set to normal? Also check for browser extensions

Comment: @Doc-Han Thanks, I've already seen [the corresponding answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24198922/1343979), but if an `<img>` element is a direct child of the `<body>` (which is the way _Mozilla_ displays images), the image gets scaled up to fill the whole body area. Which is even worse.

Comment: @jhpratt Thanks, I appreciate your effort, but, as stated above, I do need a pure CSS solution. If I could use JavaScript, I would've come up with my own solution already.

Comment: @EvgeniiMalikov Since you don't have any 4k display, no wonder you can't reproduce the behavior I've described. It's a 4k-only feature.

Comment: Unfortunately, using CSS will limit you to specific DPIs, I'll certainly give you an answer in a bit using some of the more common DPIs (like 1.5, 1.6, 2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've indicated you are solely interested in a CSS solution, I will not be including a JavaScript alternative.

Using CSS only will inherently restrict you to an enumeration of DPIs, as CSS doesn't support any way to get the *device pixel ratio*. In the future, there may be an environment variable set, though I'm not aware of any such proposal.

In my approach, I've opted to use `min-resolution` over `resolution`, as this will at least select something *close* if the exact DPI isn't matched. For this to work, you must not be setting the `width` property of the `img` elsewhere. `height` will be automatically calculated, as is the default behavior.

```css
@media (min-resolution: 1.5dppx) {
  img {
    transform: scale(calc(1 / 1.5), calc(1 / 1.5));
  }
}

@media (min-resolution: 2dppx) {
  img {
    transform: scale(calc(1 / 2), calc(1 / 2));
  }
}

@media (min-resolution: 2.5dppx) {
  img {
    transform: scale(calc(1 / 2.5), calc(1 / 2.5));
  }
}

@media (min-resolution: 3dppx) {
  img {
    transform: scale(calc(1 / 3), calc(1 / 3));
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height;">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resource://gre/res/ImageDocument.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resource://gre/res/TopLevelImageDocument.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome://global/skin/media/TopLevelImageDocument.css">

<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
```

I've only included a few here, but the general idea is pretty straightforward — scale the image down by the same amount the browser is scaling it up.

If Sass is your thing, there's a simple way to loop over your supported DPIs and generate the resulting code. A similar result can be obtained in PostCSS with a couple plugins.

```
$resolutions: 1.5 2 2.5 3

img
  @each $res in $resolutions
    @if $res != 1
      @media (min-resolution: #{$res}dppx)
        transform: scale(1 / $res, 1 / $res)
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach works, with the only drawback that the image gets scaled up to occupy the whole rectangle of the immediate parent element (`<body/>`). In other words, I need 100% of the image width, **not** 100% of the `body` element (which tends to be the width of the browser window). How do I fix that? **Update:** I've experimented with `object-fit: none`, but I can't yet confirm this latter won't mess up the scaling.

Comment: Managed to achieve partial success by using `transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);` instead of `width: calc(100% / 2);` for `2dppx`, have to further test it.

Comment: @Bass using `scale` should work as expected, at least off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

CSS has no way to use physical pixels instead of CSS pixels corresponding to pixel density (`devicePixelRatio`). The only way to prevent scaling of an image opened in a separate tab in Firefox is setting the image size dynamically via JS depending on `devicePixelRatio` and do this on each `resize` event.

Also, there is some implicit weird program logic that forces some things like cursor changes (similar — apparently hard-coded — logic sets the title of the image-view page). So the only way to get rid of this weirdness is *cloning* the image, *hiding* the original image, and dealing with the cloned copy instead. But such cloned copy is affected by so called Content Security Policy and might not be displayed at all — this is the case with e.g. user avatars on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension called [Viewhance](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/viewhance/) which implements this functionality. It is hidden behind an undocumented setting.

To tritter the switch, one needs to open the extension's configuration parameters, change to the Option/Info tab and enter `{"scaling": "*"}` prior clicking *Import*. ([source](https://github.com/Deathamns/Viewhance/issues/46#issuecomment-449468971))

Images will then be displayed at the native resolution.