# Scale images match css selector relative to their size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have to scale down images which match the following selectors:

```
img.math
div.math img
```

The problem is that I have to scale images down twice their own size — that is relative to their own size. It seems that it is only possible with javascript:

- css tricks with `width` scale images relative to the current line witdth
- css tricks with `transform` [leave empty space](http://jsfiddle.net/oy6t2xgL)

I found a js function which scales an image down [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/170642/788700):

```js
function Resize(imgId)
{
  var img = document.getElementById(imgId);
  var w = img.width, h = img.height;
  w /= 2; h /= 2;
  img.width = w; img.height = h;
}
```

the problem now is to apply that function to image matching the above mentioned selectors.

I use jQuery 1.11 and something like this is due:

```js
// resize all math images:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img.math").each(function() {
        // ???
    });
    $("div.math img").each(function() {
        // ???
    });
});
```

(this is a part of the larger `(function ($) { }(window.$jqTheme || window.jQuery));`)

**Edit**:

`img.math` is just an inline image. While `div.math img` is a numbered math equation: it also contains the equation number, which is `span` floated to the right.

**Edit 2**: Complete html section sample

The html involved is pretty basic:

```html
<div id="math" class="section">
  <span id="id1"></span><h1>Math</h1>
  <p>In-line equation: <img alt="a^2+b^2=c^2" src="_images/math/ee657daf07808119b97144fc459a5dc8839eb9c9.png" class="math">.</p>
  <p>Numbered equation:</p>
  <div id="equation-pythag" class="math">
    <p><span class="eqno">(1)</span><img alt="a^2 + b^2 = c^2" src="_images/math/53158707cc080d32d0d2f081e4bf5c6988f437ca.png"></p>
  </div><p>Link to equation: <a href="#equation-pythag">(1)</a>.</p>
</div>
```

All images staically positioned: `img.math` is just an inline image, while `div.math img` is horizontally centered in a div.

Comment: do you need to actually resize the images or just showing them smaller?

Comment: What's wrong about your jQuery code?

Comment: @domokun: yes -- because these images are of low quality (in pixel terms) and I want to hide that fact.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt: I just don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @Adobe What Erwin asked is if you want a code to manipulate the image and change the size in a canvas or you want to simply set some css to do that?

Comment: It would be beneficial to understand the context which the images will be displayed. What other elements they will interact with.

Comment: @MorganFeeney: see the edit to the post.

Comment: @Adobe I meant like will the images be floated in a paragraph, in a div with a h2 above it with an unordered list below. That kind of thing.

Comment: @MorganFeeney: nope, none of these images float. Please find a complete html section sample in *Edit 2*.

Comment: @Adobe All your images have **exactly** the same width? If they do, you can set `width:48px` and it solves the issue.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: nope. What makes you think that? Images are different. These are images of equations, and since equations are different, images are different too, in particular they have different widths.

Comment: @Adobe I suggest that you remove the `width` attribute from your code.

Comment: @Adobe Yes, but it isn't worth it since the width is calculated automatically by the browser. You don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not enough information to post in a comment, but it isn't enough for an answer.

Still, I will answer it.

Your code has to be rewritten to the following:

```
// resize all math images:
$(function() {
    $("img.math, div.math img").each(function() {
        this.width/=2;
        this.style.height='auto'; //ensures proportion
        this.style.verticalAlign='middle';
    });
});
```

All that boilerplate code can be safely eliminated.

I've removed the line `this.height/=2;` because the O.P. stated that it was causing his images to deform.

I've added the line `this.style.height='auto';` as suggested by @MorganFeeney.
It helps to ensure proportion to the image resize, in case an height it set.

Also, as the O.P. pointed out, it was needed to set `this.style.verticalAlign='middle';`.
If you are having problems with alignments, this might help. Or you can try the values `inherit` or `top`.

This method can be a little inaccurate in some situations.
For that, I recommend reading [How do I get natural dimensions of an image using javascript or jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342936/how-do-i-get-natural-dimensions-of-an-image-using-javascript-or-jquery) to get the original width and height of your image.
Also, you can read [this interesting comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342936/how-do-i-get-natural-dimensions-of-an-image-using-javascript-or-jquery#comment23410060_16342973) for a cross-browser solution.

---

As a side note:

```
$(function(){});
```

Is equivalent to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

Comment: Turns out `this.height/=2;` line is not needed. Your code actually solves the problem.

Comment: @Adobe That also depends on the case, but sometimes it's beneficial to have it there. I would recommend that you don't vote on an accepted answer so soon, since someone can come up with a better solution. I've posted this without intention of getting any reputation, but because it is too much for a comment. I'm glad it worked for you, but you should remove the mark as accepted answer, wait a few hours and then you choose the best one.

Comment: `this.height/=2;` actually deforms the image vertically. So I guess when I did `this.width/=2;` the aspect ratio has been preserved. So the `this.height/=2;` line is not just not needed, but harmful in my case.

Comment: @Adobe That may vary. But I think I can explain the behavior: When you set the `this.width/=2`, probably this triggers a re-design of the image. Then, applying `this.height/=2;` will reduce the height again. That may be the reason. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Perhaps just have the width attribute and set height: auto in css?

Comment: @MorganFeeney Now THAT is a great idea! But, for some edge cases, it will bring some harm. I will update the answer.

Comment: @MorganFeeney: Seems like it is default in browser or twitter-bootstrap -- although I don't see such rule in firebug css of these images.

Comment: @Adobe Browsers internally assume a set of styles. `height:auto;` is the default for the images. If no height is set, the image will have the original height and will scale according to the width.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel's updated answer uses it for consistency. When I scale images in the browser, whilst retaining their aspect ratio I always set the width value, and give the height a value of auto. I have never seen an adverse effect. In cases where there are problems it usually relates to a height attribute on the img element. So just get rid.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: I also have to re-inforce vertical-align: `this.style.verticalAlign = "middle";`

Comment: @Adobe That is more layout-specific, but I have added that to the answer.