# Get the natural size of an image when image is created in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, svg

Is it possible to get the natural size of a image when the image is created in javascript?

```
    var source = new Image();
    source.src = 'path/image.svg';
    console.log(source.src, source.clientWidth, source.clientHeight);
```

Are there any caveats I should be aware of when it's an svg?

Comment: If it's an SVG it might not really have a natural size. S is for scalable after all.

Comment: what about  if it wasnt how woud i get the natural size of a jpg

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342936/how-do-i-get-natural-dimensions-of-an-image-using-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: @RobertLongson that works thanks

Answer (score 0):

SVG by definition is a [Scalable Vector Graphic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) and thus does not have a set dimension.  You would need to switch to a standard image like GIF, JPG or PNG in order to retrieve the dimensions in this way.

Comment: when a svg gets rendered in the dom how does the height width get set

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342936/how-do-i-get-natural-dimensions-of-an-image-using-javascript-or-jquery this actually works

Comment: It might have set dimensions e.g `<svg width="100px" height="200px">`. And then again it might not. If it has dimensions you can certainly retrieve them.

Comment: For those bitmap formats, you need to specify whether you want its pixel dimensions or Real World measurements. PNG and JPEG may contain a resolution, but I don't think GIF has one.